# Changing SLI at runtime

Tags: sli

Is it possible to turn SLI on or off at runtime when a graphic application is running?

Or does it require a hard reboot? I'm not sure I can activate/deactivate SLI configurations at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not require a hard reboot, but you do need to close all applications using SLI.
Try direclty disabling SLI, it should list the apps that needs closure